# How to fetch data from remote url using c++ program in linux?

Tags: c++, popen

I wish to read an XML file hosted on web via my C++ program. I'm working on LINUX. 
I'm currently using popen to read.

```
FILE* remote = popen("curl 'my_url_to_xml', "r")
fread(buf, 1024, 1, remote);
```

It works and gives me the content in the url  but then it has this extra matter dumped on screen even though I'm not printing anything. Also the entire operation takes ~3000 ms. This is too much for my use case.

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0    71    0    71    0     0    309      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Any way to fix this or an alternative to popen? I wish to avoid third party libraries like libcurl. Any native solution ?

EDIT -- OK I accept even non native solutions are accepted. My first concern is popen. If this dumping problem can be fixed, I'll go with popen itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `curl` with the silent switch: `-s` OR `--silent`

Comment: thanks. Can you give me an idea how to include it with popen?

Comment: @Abhishek you would just edit the call to `curl` shown in your code and add the switch:  `popen("curl --silent 'my_url_to_xml', "r")`

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to avoid third party libraries like libcurl. Any native solution ?

No.  C++ is not a "web language" and it has zero support for XML or HTTP built in.  You need to use a library like libcurl.  Or another programming language.  Or reimplement one of those yourself.

Seriously, just use libcurl or similar and be done with it.  Or even better, use Python.  :)